# Oracle Import dump files to another user(schema)

Tags: oracle, database-administration, datapump, impdp

I am very new to DBA works. I have already exported (expdp) table and saved the dump files in a directory. I don't know the password of SCOTT user (default & example user). I want to import my tables to scott, but how can I? I am able to import (impdp) the table to system schema because I can do impdp system/password ..... because I know it's password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, run `impdp help=y` and go over the options.

Second, if you have privs for the sys schema you can access every other schema using it's name. e.g `scott.emp`. If you want to log into it directly you can just change the password.

Lastly, To import one schema into another you can use `REMAP_SCHEMA` option.